# How to save state in new Map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have 3 Groups (Group A, Group B, and Group C). Each group has checkboxes. As of right now, I'm using a react state called **checkboxStates** to store the selected options and it works just fine, but How can I store the selected values in a **new Map()** instead of a simple object?
Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

This is the Map that I would love to have when user clicks on a checkbox. If the user selects more than 1 checkbox per Group simply add it to the array.

```
{
  "Group A": [{label: "Mike", value: "mike"}],
  "Group B": [{label: "Laura", value: "laura"}],
  "Group C": [{label: "Paul", value: "paul"}],
}
```

Here's my working [**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-p9h367?file=/src/components/ListPage.tsx)

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (field, isChecked) => {
    const key = `${post.label}_${field.label}`;
    setCheckboxStates((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: isChecked
    }));
  };
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation on [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to see how it can be used? If so, is there something specific that you're struggling with?

Comment: also, "store the selected values in a new Map() instead of a simple object?" why? What's wrong with a "simple" object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `handleCheckboxChange` function to use a `Map` like so:

```js
setCheckboxStates((prevState) => {
  const next = new Map(prevState);
  next.set(post.label,
    isChecked ? [...(next.get(post.label) ?? []), { label: field.name, value: field.value }]: 
    next.get(post.label)?.filter((o) => o.label !== field.name)
  );
  return next;
});
```

Then, when mapping over the fields, change the way to check if an checkbox is checked:

```js
const isChecked = checkboxStates.get(post.label)?.some((o) => o.label === field.name) ?? false;
```

Comment: [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-gkwh89?file=/src/components/Post.tsx) (open the console to see the state)

Comment: Hi, your working demo is not displaying the user's names. I updated my Live demo please take a look at it, again. Also, I want to use a new Map() and not an Object value for checkboxStates state, how can I accomplish that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also, I believe your code breaks my “Select All” button functionally too. Any thoughts how to have that working?

Comment: @Devmix I've updated it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-gkwh89?file=/src/components/Post.tsx). I'm afraid I don't see a Select All button though.

Comment: Please, see my Live Demo link again. I have a Select All button

Comment: @Devmix Could you show the result of adding my code to it currently?

Comment: Here’s a link where I have my Select All button https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-p9h367?file=/src/components/ListPage.tsx&codemirror=1

Comment: And if I add your changes my Select All button doesn’t work anymore :(

Comment: @Devmix Could you put together a CodeSandbox after applying my changes so that I can edit that?

Comment: Yes, Here's a link that has your code changes an my Select All button: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-rcnlnw?file=/src/components/ListPage.tsx

Comment: @Devmix Here is the fixed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-nmfl4c

Comment: Nice, but I also see another issue caused by your code changes. The Search input doesnt work anymore. If you look inside of SearchBar.tsx you'll see handleSearchChange function. It doesnt work anymore.

Comment: it should allow you to do any searches. If you want to see how it should work you can click on my DEMO link to see it working just fine.

Comment: @Devmix I've fixed that [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-nmfl4c?file=/src/components/SearchBar.tsx). You were accessing a property that did not exist.

Comment: You're using the property `label` in your original code, but you've switched to using `name` in the new code. I'm not sure why this property is being renamed, but remember to keep it consistent.

Comment: Good catch, yes I want to use ```label```. But your code still doesn't work for the search

Comment: getting very close but the search has a bug still.

Comment: let's say you select ```Laura```, then in the Searchbox you type ```ar```, then delete that, then type ```au```, at this point you'll see that Laura and Paul are selected, this is wrong because I never selected Paul. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Devmix I see, I fixed it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-nmfl4c?file=/src/components/Post.tsx

Comment: One final request, please. For the new Map state, can we not display empty arrays? for example: user selects Mike from Group A, and then Steve from Group B, Finally user decides to NOT select anything from Group A so he unselects Mike. At this point, I see that we are still displaying ```Group A : []```. Can we remove a  group from Map if it's an empty array? Thank you!

Comment: @Devmix Ok: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-nmfl4c?file=/src/components/Post.tsx

Comment: You are absolutely amazing! Thanks a lot, mate!!